# Div is leaving little blank spaces and not filling width 100%

Tags: html, css

I want a straight grey line that fills the whole of the middle of my screen. I bit like a `<hr>` but I do not want to use `<hr>`. However, when I try to use it, there is always a bit of blank space on the right hand side of my div that I cannot get rid of.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id = "rule">

</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
*{
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    margin-left:0;
    mergin-right:0;
}

#rule{
    background-color:#fff;

    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

    height:40px;
    width:100%; 
    webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 3px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    box-shadow: inset 2px 3px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you have a typo in your code. In the `*` selector,  `mergin-right:0` should be `margin-right:0`.

```
* {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
}
```

[See this JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bn3CW/).

Comment: No that hasn't done it, but I feel like an idiot for that spelling mistake! haha

Comment: Hmmm. Have you tried making the width of the parent 100% (i.e. `html, body { width:100% }`

Comment: @SamStone JSW's fiddle of the code you provided (with the typo fixed) shows there's no blank space on the right.  You'll need to provide a demo of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well what I normally do at the beginning of all my CSS files is get rid of all default margins and paddings and Borders by setting everything to 0.

You can then know exactly where u stand and can add padding, margins and Borders later as u see fit.

Setting everything to zero like so:

```
*{margin: 0;padding: 0px;border:0;}
```